# Generate ID for each node in a tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, tree, anytree

I constructed a tree using anytree module in python. 
The code is as follows:

```
def list_anytree(lst):
    rootname = lst[0][0]
    node = Node(rootname)
    for j in lst:
        parentnode = node
        assert j[0] == parentnode.name
        for currentnodename in j[1:]:
            currentnode = next(
                (node for node in parentnode.children if node.name == currentnodename),
                None,
            )
            if currentnode is None:
                currentnode = Node((currentnodename), parent=parentnode)
            parentnode = currentnode
    return node

lst=[["a","b","c"],["a","b","d"],["a","b","c",]]

anytree=list_anytree(lst)
for pre,fill,node in RenderTree(anytree):
    print(f"{pre}{node.name}")
```

How can i assign a ID for each of the node in the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting tree is:

```
a
└── b
    ├── c
    └── d
```

The node object instances are somehow already an id on its own.
You can assign new attributes to objects at any time. 
For instance when you iterate over the tree

```
for idx, node in enumerate(PreOrderIter(anytree)):
    node.idx = idx
```

Or you make use of the python `id()` function, which gives a unique number. 
Please note that this number changes on every invocation:

```
for pre, fill, node in RenderTree(anytree):
    id_ = id(node)
    print(f"{pre}{node.name} {node.idx} {id_:08X}")
```

results in

```
a 0 7FE95CDB1390
└── b 1 7FE95CDB1FD0
    ├── c 2 7FE95CDC4048
    └── d 3 7FE95CDC4080
```

Comment: can i assign the node ID with help of hash functions?